# request post with retrofit in android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit2

I want use request post in my app.
I used this but I have a problem.
I face this problem when I want to create an account.

> status code 403

You can see my code:

Api.kt

```
interface Api {
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@POST("users/signup")
@FormUrlEncoded
fun createUser(
    @Field("first_name") fName: String,
    @Field("last_name") lName: String,
    @Field("email") email: String,
    @Field("username") username: String,
    @Field("password") password: String,
) : Call<UserResponse>
}
```

UserResponse.kt

```
data class UserResponse(
val email: String,
val first_name: String,
val password: String,
val last_name: String,
val username: String
)
```

SignUpActivity.kt

```
binding.btnSignUp
        .setOnClickListener {

            val username = binding.etUsername.text.toString().trim()
            val password = binding.etPw.text.toString().trim()
            val fName = binding.etFName.text.toString().trim()
            val lName = binding.etLName.text.toString().trim()
            val email = binding.etEmail.text.toString().trim()

            if (username.isEmpty()) {
                binding.etUsername.error = "Password required"
                binding.etUsername.requestFocus()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            if (password.isEmpty()) {
                binding.etPw.error = "Password required"
                binding.etPw.requestFocus()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()

            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging)
            val instance: Api by lazy {

                val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build()
                retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
            }
            instance.createUser(fName, lName, email, username, password)
                .enqueue(object : Callback<UserResponse> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<UserResponse>,
                        response: Response<UserResponse>
                    ) {
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show()
                    }
                })

        }
```

I use this request on postman and it works good

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSnGQ.png)

but in android studio it didn't work
and I have this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zezw.png)

I hope u can help me

Comment: Try setting up ```android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"``` in the ```<application>``` tag in ```AndroidManifest.xml```

Comment: @KishanMevada I have done this before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the some modification, you can make :

step: 1 Add this permission in your `AndroidMenifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

step: 2

`UserResponse.java`

```
public class UserResponse {

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    @Expose
    private String firstName;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    @Expose
    private String lastName;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("groups")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> groups = null;
    @SerializedName("permissions")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> permissions = null;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<Object> getGroups() {
        return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(List<Object> groups) {
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    public List<Object> getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    public void setPermissions(List<Object> permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

}
```

Step: 3 -> Add this methods to your activity and call method `apiCall()` in your onCreate() or appropriate place.

```
private fun getClient(): Retrofit? {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        val client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build()
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://194.62.43.26:1337/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()
    }

    private fun apiCall() {

        val firstname = "123"
        val lastname = "234"
        val email = "345@6.com"
        val username = "132456"
        val pw = "12345678"

        val call = getClient()!!.create(Api::class.java).createUser(
            firstname,
            lastname,
            email,
            username,
            pw
        )

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<UserResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<UserResponse>, response: Response<UserResponse>) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, response.code().toString()
                        + " " + response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<UserResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, t.localizedMessage!!.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    }
```

Step: 4 Response is in the screen shot [image: screen shot - response]

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: I did everything you said, but this happens again.https://pasteboard.co/Rq2oFpChtHvD.png

Comment: is internet permission added ?

Comment: incase problem is still there, you can download & run your api solution project that i have made from this link : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8308d80fcb034094ccdef0efdf66774020220706063551/f3b02a

Comment: yes internet permission add ....   Why is this code in Java? UserResponse.kt

Comment: if you can see my project in github https://github.com/Saeedmoeen/App

Comment: I have just downloaded your project and it is working fine, actually i have created one fake user also and got this response : {"id":22,"first_name":"nfnfndn","last_name":"c c c f","email":"nfnfndn@email.com","username":"fndnfncn","groups":[],"permissions":[]}

Comment: my code work for u ? create user  ?

Comment: Try changing your wifi or celluar data connections.

Comment: Yes, your code is working, here,

Comment: u run my project with emulator ? like this  https://pasteboard.co/xXaSDlB6mfxR.png

Comment: See point no 5 :  incase you missed this from link.  https://gadgetstouse.com/blog/2021/05/17/android-apps-not-working-on-mobile-data/

Comment: Yes, i have run project in real device, got same interface as you showed in emulator, created one user also, you can check in your database.

Comment: u can check this with emulator ?

Comment: Just run with emulator, and also created one user, you can check success response in logcat with this screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/BGutYYDy4vmc.png

Comment: yesss this work for me i just disable proxy in my android studio ... ty bro I was involved in this for 5 days. Can I have your ID on the social network?

Comment: Linked IN : https://in.linkedin.com/in/kishan-mevada-035927110?original_referer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F